# How can I create a model object with deeply nested associations in Rails using only my params whitelist method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

To replicate this question, my base model is `project`:

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :tones, as: :analyzable
  has_many :sentences
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tones, :sentences
end
```

And I have two other models:

```
class Sentence < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :project
  has_many :tones, as: :analyzable
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tones
end

class Tone < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :analyzable, polymorphic: true
end
```

In my ProjectsController, I want to have a single create action that just takes in the whitelisted params and creates a project with all the appropriate associations. My project_params method looks like this:

```
private
  def project_params
    params.permit(:text, :title, :img, sentences_attributes: [:id, :text, tones_attributes: [:score, :tone_name]], tones_attributes: [:id, :score, :tone_name])
  end
```

But if I try something like:

```
project = Project.create(project_params)
```

I will get an error like the one below:

```
| ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch (Sentence(#70119358770360) expected, got {"text"=>"extremely disappointed with the level of service with Virgin Media.", "tones"=>[{"score"=>0.64031, "tone_name"=>"Sadness"}, {"score"=>0.618451, "tone_name"=>"Confident
"}]} which is an instance of ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess(#70119356172580)):
```

I ended up writing this for my create action, which gets the job done but feels quite clumsy:

```
    project = Project.create({text: params[:text], title: params[:title], 
    img: params[:img]})
    params[:sentences].each do |sent|
      sentence = project.sentences.create({text: sent["text"]})
      sent["tones"].each do |tone|
        sentence.tones.create({score: tone["score"], tone_name: tone["tone_name"]})
      end
    end

    params[:tones].each do |tone|
      project.tones.create({score: tone["score"], tone_name: tone["tone_name"]})
    end
```

Is there a better way to handle this kind of situation than what I have immediately above, where one is trying to create an object from nested params that has several levels of association?

Comment: Do you use `f.fields_for` for sentences and for tones? and why you have tone as `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in Project if it is already defined in sentence ?

Comment: Another thing, do you have a direct relation between Project and tone ?

Comment: The idea is that a project can have many tones (as a whole), and that every sentence of a project can also have many tones. So yes, project is directly related to tones via has many.

Comment: Please post the entire `params` hash.